# React Context based on props

Tags: reactjs

I have a component with the following code:

```
getChildContext = () => {
  return {
    language: this.props.lang
  }
}
```

`this.props.lang` is based on some state higher up in my component hierarchy.

I noticed that whenever `this.props.lang` changes, the `this.context.language` in a component that accesses the `context` stays the same as the original `this.props.lang`. It's like the initial props flow down, but the rest doesn't.

Any ideas on how to resolve this one? Is this normal behavior the context doesn't automatically change when the props it's based on change?

Comment: Good question, I have vague memories of checking the react source and seeing it does a shallow copy for every child using the context and doesn't update unfortunately, but interested to see what others say about it

Comment: Apparently this is a known bug because of  shouldcomponentupdate: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/2517